# How to format numbers into currency by Google Script from cells in Google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I currently have a financial Google sheet I'm pulling data from and throwing (populating) into documents using a script.

I am having trouble having the numbers come in the proper currency format, which in my case is 34.042,41 €. (euro, '.' and then ',' for decimals)

I have this script at the moment:

```
body2.replaceText('{{Sum Onsite}}', formatcurrency(row[25]));
```

Where text is replaced by the input function.

And at the bottom I created this other function to format the input into the desired output:

```
function formatcurrency(currency) {
var currency = new Currency();
return Utilities.formatcurrency("€#.##0,00;€(#.##0,00)")
}
```

The error I get with this is that the 'Currency is not defined' and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated. If you need more detail do let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Show your input data. Implementation depends on what you have: number or strings, and how they look like.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your figures look like. Suppose they look like this `123,123.12` and you want they look like this `123.123,12 €`

Here you go:

```js
function euro(n) {
  return n.replace(/\,/g, '_').replace(/\./, ',').replace(/_/g, '.') + '€';
}

console.log(euro('123,123.12')); // 123.123,12€
```

Comment: Interesting way to do it.

it looks like this 123123.12 at the moment. But I found a workaround that will work.
Will post here.

Answer (score 1):

I found this works:

```
function formatSalary(salary){
  return new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE',{style:'currency',currency:'EUR'}).format(salary)
  }
```

and

```
body2.replaceText('{{Rechnungsbetrag}}', formatSalary(row[28]));
```

Comment: Looks smart. I definitely will use it.